# Unity NetworkServer / NetworkClient transferring GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, spawn, unity-networking

I'm working on unity networking between NetworkServer/NetworkClient. I don't use NetworkManager

Here is part of my code of client.

```
public void StartPaintClient()
{
    client = new NetworkClient();
    client.Connect(host, port);
    client.RegisterHandler(NetworkMeta.PaintPrefabId, OnMouseButtonDown);
}
public void OnMouseButtonDown(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    var receivedPrefab = netMsg.ReadMessage<NetworkMeta.PaintPrefab>();
    GameObject prefab = Instantiate(receivedPrefab.p);
    prefab.name = "" + index++;

}
```

Here is part of my code of server.

```
public GameObject prefab;
public void StartPaintServer()
{

    if (NetworkServer.active)
    {
        Debug.Log("Server is already acitve");
        return;
    }
    NetworkServer.Listen(port);
}
void Update()
{
     if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
     {
          prefab = Instantiate(Line_Prefab);
          var newPrefab = new NetworkMeta.PaintPrefab();
          newPrefab.p = prefab;
          NetworkServer.SendToAll(NetworkMeta.PaintPrefabId, newPrefab);
     }
}
```

I have two questions.

1. The reason why I use `NetworkServer.SendToAll(msgType, msg)` instead of `NetworkServer.Spawn(obj)` is didn't worked at all even if there was no console error. What are possible reasons of that?
2. The codes above also has trouble. The colsole error msg whenever `NetworkServer.SendToAll(mspType, msg)` causes

> ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.

I don't understand why newPrefab.p  is null.... 
Any Idea for a newbie of network programming?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Unet and don't know much about it but you must do the following before spawning a prefab.

**1**.The prefab must have [`NetworkIdentity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkIdentity.html) script attached to it.

**2**.You must register the prefab before you can spawn it.

```
Networking.ClientScene.RegisterPrefab(Line_Prefab);
```

then you can use `NetworkServer.Spawn`.

```
var line = (GameObject)Instantiate(Line_Prefab, pos, rot);
NetworkServer.Spawn(line);
```

Notice that I am **not** using `NetworkServer.Spawn` directly on the prefab. I had to use it on the GameObject spawned with `(GameObject)Instantiate(Line_Prefab, pos, rot);`.

Also make sure that you assigned the prefab from the Editor to your variable. You can learm more about spawing Objects on the network [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html).

Comment: What if I want to separate server code from client code? where should that prefab be stored? in both sides (it does not seems to be good)?